# Compiler Optimization with return (std::stringstream ss).str()

Tags: c++, rvo, nrvo

The following function accepts a string as an argument, and returns another, after some processing.

1. Is it fair enough to assume that the compiler will perform move optimizations, and I will not end up having the contents of string copied after every invocation? Should this function follow the [copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261145/compiler-optimization)  [(N)RVO]?
2. Is this, as a practice, advisable?

```cpp
std::string foo(std::string const& s)
{ // Perform sanity check on s
  // ...

  std::stringstream ss;
  // do something and store in ss
  // ...

  return ss.str();
}
```

Because, otherwise, I generally follow the practice of returning strings by reference. So, to say, my function signature would have been:

```cpp
void foo (std::string const& inValue, std::string& outValue);
```

Comment: you have nothing to worry about, the compiler will optimize the copying away either by moving or eliding.

Comment: If you put `s` in that `stringstream` then I am pretty sure it will be copied on the way in and copied on the way out.

Comment: You could write `return std::move(ss).str()`, just in case your implementation optimizes this case (not sure if any does yet).

Comment: I can understand the return move(); part! But I can not understand the latter part of your comment `not sure if any does yet'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ss.str()` will create a temporary string.  If you are assigning that string to a a new instance like

```
std::string bar = foo("something");
```

The either copy elision or move semantics will kick in.

Now if you have an already created string and you are assigning it to the return of `foo` then move assignment will kick in

```
std::string bar;
// do stuff
bar  = foo("something");
```

I prefer this method as it does not require you to have an object already created where

```
void foo (std::string const& inValue, std::string& outValue);
```

Would have you create an empty string just to pass it to the function to get filled.  This means you have a construction and a assignment where with the first example you could just have a construction.

Comment: I had missed out on the details of the `call site'! Thanks for illustrating in depth.

Comment: @bvraghav No problem.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://blog.knatten.org/2011/08/26/dont-be-afraid-of-returning-by-value-know-the-return-value-optimization/) it is more optimized when you return the value:

> the Return Value Optimization (RVO), allows the compiler to optimize away the copy by having the caller and the callee use the same chunk of memory for both “copies”.